# All Listview data show in textbox using loop

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
    Dim Mysqlconn = New SqlConnection
    Mysqlconn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"

    Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable("studentdata")

    Mysqlconn.Open()

    Dim query As String
    query = "select ID from studentdata where Class='" & ComboBox1.Text & "'"

    Dim Command = New SqlCommand(query, Mysqlconn)
    Dim dr = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    ListView1.Items.Clear()
    Dim x As ListViewItem

    Do While dr.Read = True
        x = New ListViewItem(dr("ID").ToString)
        ListView1.Items.Add(x)
    Loop

    For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
        TextBox1.Text = ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text
    Next
```

In this code, `Textbox1` is showing the last row from `Listview1`. My requirement is all the Listview1 data show in textbox1 one after one from Listview1. Is this possible to show in textbox1 read all data from Listview1 using loop. Thank you...

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary vulnerable to sql injection issues. It's never okay to use string concatenation like that to include a value in an sql query. This is one of those things that's too important to do wrong even for practice/learning/proof of concept projects.

Comment: `TextBox1.Text += ListView1.Items(i).SubItems(0).Text + Environment.NewLine;`

Comment: @Chetan, Thank you for respond. as per your suggestion I tried this code but it's showing all the values in Textbox1(1001100210031004). I want to read values one after one into textbox1. Thank you...

Comment: is your textbox multiline? If not you need to make  the textbox multiline first. With that my code will show one value per line in the textbox.

Comment: @Chetan, I changed textbox1 to Multiline, now it's holding 1st row, it's not going for not going for next row...

Comment: How many items you have in the ListView? Are you using the exactly same code as I shared? Can you make sure that the code have `+=` and not just `=`?

Comment: @Chetan, I have 50 Items in Listview1 and I used +=.

Answer (score 0):

A textbox only holds one string at a time. If it's set to allow multiline strings (not clear in the question) you can separate each item with a linebreak. Otherwise you can separate the strings using a delimiter like a comma.

```
Dim query As String = "select ID from studentdata where Class= @class"
Using conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-D32ONKB;Initial Catalog=Attendance;Integrated Security=True"), _
      cmd  As New SqlCommand(query, conn)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20).Value =  ComboBox1.Text
    conn.Open()
    Using dr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        While dr.Read()
            ListView1.Items.Add(New ListViewItems(dr("ID").ToString()))
        End While
    End Using
End Using

TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", ListView1.Items.Select(Function(i) i.SubItems(0).Text))
```

Also note how I used a query parameter to include the combobox value in the SQL command. That's a **big deal**; anything else *will* give you trouble, usually sooner than later.

Comment: TextBox1.Text = String.Join(",", ListView1.Items.Select(Function(i) i.SubItems(0).Text)) in this line 'select' showing error line "select is not a member of 'Listview.Listviewitemcollection'"

Answer (score 0):

Using as loop, the proper way would be like so:

```vb
Dim lines As New List(Of String)

For i = 0 To ListView1.Items.Count - 1
    lines.Add(ListView1.Items(i).Text)
Next

TextBox1.Lines = lines.ToArray()
```

You can't keep setting the `Text` property to a new value and expect the old value to hang around for no reason. You could append to the `Text` each time, but that is inefficient. The proper way is to create a list of the values, convert that to a `String` array and then assign that to the `Lines` property.

Note that there is no point getting the `Text` of the first subitem because that is the same as the `Text` of the item.